# vertical full page width & height accordion type menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am really working hard on this one but not coming to conclusion. This is what like my HTML and CSS look now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="static"><a href="#"><img src="unai.jpg"/></a></div>
        <div class="menu"><div class="content"></div>   <a href="#"><img src="unai.jpg"/></a></div>
        <div class="menu"><div class="content"></div>   <a href="#"><img src="unai.jpg"/></a></div>
        <div class="menu"><div class="content"></div>   <a href="#"><img src="unai.jpg"/></a></div>
        <div class="menu"><div class="content"></div>   <a href="#"><img src="unai.jpg"/></a></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript2.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    }

html, body, #wrapper, #wrapper div{
    height:100%;
    }

#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper #static{
        float: left;
        }

    #wrapper > div{ 
        position: relative;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #9F81F7;      
        float: right;
        z-index: 9999;
        }
        #wrapper div.content{
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0.01;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            z-index: -1;
            }
        #wrapper div:last-child:after{
            content: " ";
            clear: both;
        }

    #wrapper a{
        width: 137px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left: 68px;
        margin-top: -106px;
    }
```

And what I need to achieve is:

[image: ACCORDION]

I've been sitting all day on this one but nothing yet. Have tried some JQuery code but nothing seems to do what I need.
All I need is to achieve this accordion effect. Rest can do myself.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You said you've tried some jQuery already--it would help to see that. It's really overambitious to just ask for the whole snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is pretty simple. You want to capture the click event on the image, reset the width of all the siblings of the pressed image's parent container, and then proceed to stretch its width.

Something as simple as this works:

```
$(document).on("click", "#wrapper div.content a", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this
        .closest("div.content")
        .css("width","300px")
        .siblings()
        .css("width","50px");
});
```

`on()` was added to jQuery as of version 1.7. If you're using an earlier version, use `live()` or `bind()`. Keep in mind that the syntax of the function changed, so be attentive.

The closer the parent you can get in place of `document`, the better the event delegation.

`300px` and `50px` are just examples in this case. You can use whatever width you want.

And in terms of full page-width, Apple.com does a very sneaky thing with their nav to comply with their expanding search bar. They've applied `display:table-cell` on each of the nav elements so that when one expands, so does the other. It's very ingenious, actually, and you can apply it to your situation.